# About sum using AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have an table, in aws athena.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3inventory(
         bucket string,
         key string,
         version_id string,
         is_latest boolean,
         is_delete_marker boolean,
         size string,
         last_modified_date string,
         e_tag string,
         storage_class string,
         is_multipart_uploaded boolean,
         replication_status string,
         encryption_status string,
         object_lock_retain_until_date string,
         object_lock_mode string,
         object_lock_legal_hold_status string,
         intelligent_tiering_access_tier string,
         bucket_key_status string,
         checksum_algorithm string
) PARTITIONED BY (
        dt string
```

And I need to sum the field `size`, but even changing the field still the error that doesn't convert , they said that cant sum the number.

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Unexpected parameters (varchar) for function sum. Expected: sum(double) , sum(real) , sum(bigint) , sum(interval day to second) , sum(interval year to month) , sum(decimal(p,s))

Comment: I would say that error is pretty self-explonatory. Can you please show the query you are attempting and sample data with sample desired output?

Comment: The `size` field is defined as `string` (which is **text**). It is not possible to 'sum' text. If the data in the file is a number, it would be easiest to re-run the DDL to create the field as a number, eg `size int` rather than `size string`. Alternatively, case it with `SUM(CAST(size AS int))`